# How can I print xml file with gb2312 using lxml in python

Tags: python-3.x, lxml

```
filePath = "Black1.xml"
xml_file =  open(filePath, 'r')
tree = etree.parse(filePath, etree.XMLParser(encoding="gb2312"))
root = tree.getroot()
print (etree.tostring(root, encoding = 'gb2312'))
```

I use above code print gb2312 xml  file, but It output messy code.Is there a proper method for print gb2312 xml file?
   the origin file content is:
[image]

but the print content is:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "it output messy code" -  you need to show an example of what you mean - no one has your system/file to see for themselves... You'll also need to explain what are you expecting instead of what you're getting?

Comment: such as "explain="&#26631;&#20934;&#26631;&#39064;&#26639;&#32972;&#26223;&#39068;&#33394"", I expect the output is "explain = "颜色"", "颜色“is gb2312 code.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that example so it's formatted properly and part of the question itself.